# Beginner looking to try a short CG film, any suggestions for software?

Tags: software-recommendation, short

Sorry if I'm using the wrong terminology or anything, I've never done anything like this before.

I'd like to try my hand at making a short 2-3 min film in CG. What I'm kinda envisioning is something like the clone wars series on disney+, but I think that's probably a bit advanced. I checked around the site a it, and found these two([1](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30935/software-choosing-advice-for-a-beginner) [2](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17876/storyboarding-for-beginners)) questions that were kinda helpful for transitions and storyboarding, but I still don't really know where I should be making the actual video. [This question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30191/tool-to-make-a-short-youtube-video) had some suggestions, but I'm still just a beginner and don't really know what I'm doing. Are these good suggestions, or do I need something else?

Since I've never done anything like this before and will probably be bad at it, I'm preferably looking for a free software, or a short subscription or cheap app. That way if I suck, its not that big of a loss. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could check out Blender. It's free and there are a lot of tutorials. I'm not doing much animations, so can't help you further.

Comment: Lower your expectations. 2 or 3 minutes of CG can take you MONTHS even when you know what you are doing.

Make a short clip of 10 seconds first.

Answer (score 1):

Months ago, I'd done some researches on this topic; even i had CG background, i don't have much time on modeling. My suggestion for you is to do [How to Create 2D Animations - Beginner Blender Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Or1HtAG9M-s) firstly, then https://conceptartempire.com/blender-animation-tutorials/